# LSB steganography with pure Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, steganography

As this is pure Python so using loop with big files make the code very slow
any improvements or suggestions.

**Hide Code**

```
 # Consts
HEADER_SIZE = 54
DELIMITER = "$"

class LSBEncrypter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image_byte_counter = 0
        self.new_image_data = ''
        self.original_image = ''
        self.text_to_hide = ''

    def open_image(self):
        with open(ImageFile, "rb") as f:
            self.original_image = ''.join(map(chr, f.read()))
    def read_header(self):
        for x in range(0, HEADER_SIZE):
            self.new_image_data += self.original_image[x]
            self.image_byte_counter += 1
    def hide_text_size(self):
        sz = len(self.text_to_hide)
        s_sz = str(sz)
        s_sz += DELIMITER
        self.do_steg(s_sz)

    def do_steg(self, steg_text):

        for ch in range(0, len(steg_text)):

            current_char = steg_text[ch]
            current_char_binary = '{0:08b}'.format(ord(current_char))
            for bit in range(0, len(current_char_binary)):
                new_byte_binary = ''

                current_image_binary = '{0:08b}'.format(ord(self.original_image[self.image_byte_counter]))

                new_byte_binary = current_image_binary[:7]

                new_byte_binary += current_char_binary[bit]

                new_byte = chr(int(new_byte_binary, 2))

                self.new_image_data += new_byte
                self.image_byte_counter += 1
    def copy_rest(self):
        self.new_image_data += self.original_image[self.image_byte_counter:]

    def close_file(self):
        with open(StegImageFile, "wb") as out:
            out.write(bytearray(map(ord, self.new_image_data)))

    def run(self, stega_text):
        self.text_to_hide = stega_text
        self.open_image()
        self.read_header()
        self.hide_text_size()
        self.do_steg(self.text_to_hide)
        self.copy_rest()
        self.close_file()

    def hide_(self, Texte, image, steg):
        global TextToHide, ImageFile, StegImageFile
        TextToHide = Texte
        ImageFile = image
        StegImageFile = steg
        stega_instance = LSBEncrypter()
        stega_instance.run(TextToHide)
```

**Reveal Code**

```
 import binascii

HEADER_SIZE = 54
DELIMITER = "$"

class LSBDecrypter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.StegImageFile = ''
        # self.fh = open(StegImageFile, 'rb')
        self.number_of_chars_in_text = 0
        self.original_text = ''

    def read_header(self):
        self.fh = open(StegImageFile, 'rb')
        for i in range(0, HEADER_SIZE):
            byte = self.fh.read(1)

    def get_char(self):
        new_byte = ''

        for bit in range(0, 8):
            byte = self.fh.read(1)

            new_byte += str(ord(byte) & 0x01)

        n = int(new_byte, 2)
        desteg_char = binascii.unhexlify('%x' % n)
        desteg_char = ''.join(map(chr, desteg_char))
        return desteg_char

    def get_text_size(self):
        curr_ch = self.get_char()

        s_sz = ''

        while curr_ch != DELIMITER:
            s_sz += curr_ch
            curr_ch = self.get_char()

        if (s_sz != ''):
            self.number_of_chars_in_text = int(s_sz)

    def read_stega_text(self):
        decoded_chars = 0;
        while decoded_chars < self.number_of_chars_in_text:
            self.original_text += self.get_char()
            decoded_chars += 1

    def close_file(self):
        self.fh.close();

    def get_text(self):
        self.read_header()
        self.get_text_size()
        self.read_stega_text()
        self.close_file()
        return self.original_text

    def reveal_(self, stego):
        global StegImageFile
        StegImageFile = stego
        destag_insta = LSBDecrypter()
        text = destag_insta.get_text()
        print (text)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Performance:

```python
def get_char(self):
    new_byte = ''

    for bit in range(0, 8):
        byte = self.fh.read(1)

        new_byte += str(ord(byte) & 0x01)

    n = int(new_byte, 2)
    desteg_char = binascii.unhexlify('%x' % n)
    desteg_char = ''.join(map(chr, desteg_char))
    return desteg_char
```

This is not as simple as it could be. You are reading 8 bits as strings to build a single byte, converting it to an integer, then to a hex string (string format before unhexlify), then to a hexadecimal string, then mapping to a character, and then joining them together. I recommend doing more math and less string conversion and concatenation.

### Style:

**1. Use consistent string delimiters**

- You have `'` in most places, like `open(StegImageFile, 'rb')`, but you also have `DELIMITER = "$"` and `open(StegImageFile, "wb")`. Use `'` everywhere if that's what you're using.

**2. Remove unnecessary parentheses**

- `if (s_sz != ''):` should be `if s_sz != '':`, or even more concise: `if s_sz:`.

**3. Consider meaningful variable names**

- `s_sz` isn't a helpful variable name, and I don't know what it is at a glance, other than that it's the string form of `sz` (also not helpful).

**4. Remove the space in `print (text)`**

- You don't use spaces after any other function names.

**5. Remove weird leading spaces**

- The space before `# Consts`
- The space before `import binascii`